# Why Bousfield localization preserves homotopy pull-backs?

Tags: stable-homotopy-theory, pullback

Studying chromatic homotopy theory I encountered the chromatic fracture square
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    L_{K(n) \vee K(m)}X @>>> L_{K(m)}X\\
    @V  V V @VV  V\\
    L_{K(n)}X @>>> L_{K(n)}L_{K(m)}X
\end{CD}
for $n<m$. Then I was told that applying a Bousfield localization functor we preserve the homotopy pull-back, this is useful since applying $L_{K(t)}$ for $n <t<m$ we get the equality $L_{K(t)}L_{K(n)\vee K(m)}X= L_{K(t)}L_{K(m)}X $
since the lower terms become zero.

I would like to know a proof of this claim. Also a reference for this fact is well accepted.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I just need to observe that the Bousfield localization, being a left adjoint, preserves homotopy colimits. Now by stability of the stable homotopy category homotopy pull-backs and pushouts coincide.